# save mysql results to datatable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have just switched to using parameters for mysql queries and fear I can not find how to save my results to a data table. I want to save the results of this select query to datatable "table". Previously I would have done

```
adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from users WHERE uname='" & MySqlHelper.EscapeString(UsernameTextBox.Text) & "' and pword=md5('" & MySqlHelper.EscapeString(PasswordTextBox.Text) & "')", con)
    Try
        adptr.Fill(table)
    Catch err As Exception
        Dim strError As String = "Exception: & err.ToString()"
    End Try
```

now I have

```
    Public table As New DataTable
    Dim cb As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    cb.Database = dbfile
    cb.Server = dbserver
    cb.UserID = dbuser
    cb.Password = dbpassw

    Using cnn As New MySqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * from users WHERE uname=&uname and pword=md5(&pword)", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UsernameTextBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", PasswordTextBox.Text)

            Try
                cnn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

how do I save the results to table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Command to initialize the adapter and then work as before

```
Using cnn As New MySqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * from users WHERE uname=&uname and pword=md5(&pword)", cnn)
        cnn.Open
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("&uname", UsernameTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("&pword", PasswordTextBox.Text)
        adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adptr.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using
```

ExecuteNonQuery should be used for queries that change the database table (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) or other DDL commands. In your case the prepared command could be used for one of the overladed constructor of the MySqlDataAdapter (Look at this docs for [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) they have the same logical effect)

Also I am not sure that the MySqlParameter prefix is `&` (I have always used `@` or `?`)

Comment: if using &uname the parameter would have to be changed also - @ does also work though - thanks for the answer